# What is the probability of escape (read the full question to understand, its probability)

Tags: probability

About 1000 years ago, when a thief was caught in Baghdad, he or she was thrown into a dark dungeon with three doors.

One door led to freedom after one hour of travelling.

The second door led into a tunnel which deposited the thief back in the dungeon after two days' travel.

The third door led into a tunnel which returned to the dungeon after three days' travel.

On being thrown into the dungeon each thief was given enough food and drink for five days and one hour. What is the probability of escape if doors are chosen at random?

Replace the 2-day tunnel by a 1-day tunnel and reduce the food and drink supply to four days and one hour.Now what is the probability of escape if doors are chosen at random?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more we know about your thoughts and efforts, the easier it will be for us to gauge your experience level and tailor our answers to your needs. Also, many on this site won't even bother to help someone who posts an answer with no motivation or demonstration of effort.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of escape is $\frac{2}{3}$.

There are six successful ways to escape:

He chooses door 1

He chooses door 2, then 1

He chooses door 3, then 1

He chooses door 2, then 2, then 1

He chooses door 2, then 3, then 1

He chooses door 3, then 2, then 1

Any other choice combinations will result in death.

The probability that he will make choose the "correct" next door for a specific pattern is $\frac{1}{3}$, and the probability that he survives is the sum of these probabilities.

P = $\frac{1}{3}$ + $\frac{1}{3^2}$ + $\frac{1}{3^2}$ + $\frac{1}{3^3}$ + $\frac{1}{3^3}$ + $\frac{1}{3^3}$ = $\frac{18}{27}$ = $\frac{2}{3}$

Apply similar logic to the second question, and the answer is $\frac{166}{243}$

I don't think this question belongs here as it seems that you are not attempting it yourself and struggling, but merely posting it for others to solve. If so, this may belong on Puzzling SE

Answer (score 0):

If the thief knows the information about the doors, then the probability of escape is 100% in the 1st case, and 2/3 in the 2nd case, because he could

1. Pick a door and travel for 1 hour.
2. If he was not free, then return to the dungeon.
3. Pick another door and travel for 1 hour.
4. If he was not free, then return to the dungeon.
5. Pick the unpicked door and walk to freedom.